# Python Selenium no such element: unable to locate xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to auto-login to a bet site that i'm a user, but i can't complete the login because the selenium can't find the xpath. Here is the code that i am using so far:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import login_data

def main():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    options.headless = False
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Users\bilakos\Documents\DRIVERS\chromedriver.exe')
    browser.get("https://en.stoiximan.gr/")
    sleep(5)

    login_data.login(browser)


main()
```

Here is the import code:

```
def login(browser):
    username = 'Username'
    password = 'password'

    #Here is the first login button that is needed to be clicked before i'm gonna enter my data
    login = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="landing-page-modal"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/p[2]/a""")
    login.click()
    sleep(5)

    #Here is the place i enter my username
    username_input = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="js-login-form"]/div[1]/div[1]/input""")
    username_input.click()
    username_input.send_keys(username)

    #Here is the place i enter my password
    password_input = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="js-login-form"]/div[2]/div[1]/input""")
    password_input.click()
    password_input.send_keys(password)

    #Here i'm clicking the login button to login to my account
    login_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="js-login-button"]""")
    login_button.click()
```

And here is the error that i am getting:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="js-login-form"]/div[2]/div[1]/input"}
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)
```

The problem occurs both to the username and password xpaths. If someone has a solution i will be thankful.

The linκ of the site is:  https://en.stoiximan.gr/

Comment: I can't login the website from my country though... did you try it without the `*` from `"//*[@id="js-login-button"]"`?

Comment: I see an error as _...Error 1009 Ray ID: 608994f32af5e2d1 • 2020-12-28 07:31:27 UTC
Access denied
What happened?
The owner of this website (en.stoiximan.gr) has banned the country or region your IP address is in (IN) from accessing this website.

Cloudflare Ray ID: 608994f32af5e2d1 • Your IP: 152.57.93.232 • Performance & security by Cloudflare..._

Comment: To sammy --- Without the `*` didn't work either. If you guys can't login cause to country restrictions is one way road for me. Thanks for the interest so!

Comment: I looked at the html and saw that the modal was an iframe. So I tried using the url directly `browser.get("https://en.stoiximan.gr/myaccount/login")`, which worked. I then used the css selectors `'.old-school-login .js-username-field'` and `'.old-school-login .js-password-field'`, but I believe the xpaths would work there too. But as I have no real login data, I could not verify, that you would be redirected to the main page.

Comment: @NationBoneless Bro wtf!!! I'm trying all the day to get it work and you fix it with a simple change to the url xD .... love you man you are the best, thank you so so so match you open my blind eyes!!!
Can you tell me how you thought this solution?

Comment: It's a little bit avoiding the problem ^^ I first tried to check the xpath you used for any mistakes, but it worked for me too. Then i opened a python console and put in the command line by line. It still gave the same error. Then I tried via css_selectors, but still got the error. And while looking at css classes to use, I realized that the whole modal was in an iframe. I was wondering, whether that could cause some issues, but couldn't find anything. The change of the url was the next best thing I thought of ^^

Comment: @NationBoneless Your thought about changing the url was a genius move from my perspective. I was waiting for an answer like parenting elements but changing the url ... man that was unbelievable